# Swipe Between Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, swipe

I have 2 activities where i want to switch between them with swipe, i've done a lot of research on google but couldn't find a solution, as i am working with bitmaps (images) i have most of code written inside the onCreate() method of Activity, is there any solution for this, or how can i convert the activity like it is into a fragment

Comment: Why dont you use Fragments with ViewPager?

Comment: i have created an activity to display sdcard images and to select from them so i can display in the other activity (edit activity) where i can edit them, i don't know if i can convert activity into fragment exactly like it is now

Comment: It's not hard to convert, just a little changes in activities will do the job! Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using GestureDetector. Below is the sample snippet.

```
// You can change values of below constants as per need.
private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
private static final int MAX_OFF_PATH = 200;
private static final int THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100;
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

// write below code in onCreate method
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new SwipeDetector());

// Set touch listener to parent view of activity layout
// Make sure that setContentView is called before setting touch listener.
findViewById(R.id.parent_view).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // Let gesture detector handle the event
                return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });


// Define a class to detect Gesture
private class SwipeDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            if (e1 != null && e2 != null) {
                float dy = e1.getY() - e2.getY();
                float dx = e1.getX() - e2.getX();

                // Right to Left swipe
                if (dx > MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(dy) < MAX_OFF_PATH &&
                        Math.abs(velocityX) > THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            // Add code to change activity  
                    return true;
                }

                // Left to right swipe
                else if (-dx > MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(dy) < MAX_OFF_PATH &&
                        Math.abs(velocityX) > THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            // Below is sample code to show left to right swipe while launching next activity
           currentActivity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.right_out);
           startActivity(new Intent(currentActivity,NextActivity.class));
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
}

//Below are sample animation xml files.

anim/right_in.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>

anim/right_out.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

Comment: It is working fine , thank you, but what i want is to see the slide effect and the activity to be turned on already, after all these tries i am considering to convert every activity into fragments, thank you again !

Comment: For slide effect you can use animation and activity's overridePendingTransition method..Check my updated answer. but yes I agree using fragment is correct way.

Comment: i have already achieved the result i wanted using fragments, thanks again for answer !

Answer (score 1):

There are some libraries for you:

1. https://github.com/ikew0ng/SwipeBackLayout
2. https://github.com/liuguangqiang/SwipeBack
3. https://github.com/sockeqwe/SwipeBack